# jQuery Replace Text Inside Tag with No Attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, equals

I'm looking to replace the text inside a `<nobr>` but I can't figure out how.

It would be easy if I could do:

```
$('nobr:contains("Due")').replace('Due Date');
```

but there's another `<nobr>` that has the word `"Due"` in it and I don't want that affected.

What's the simplest way to find the `<nobr>` that's exactly equal to `"Due"` and replace it with `"Due Date"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) all the `nobr` elements to eliminate any whose text is not equal to "Due":

```
$("nobr").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "Due";
}).text("Due Date");
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/APzxv/4/).

Comment: Works like a charm. +1 for the jsfiddle. Thanks!